# Upgrade Squeeze to Wheezy now no modules.dep

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, upgrade, kernel-modules

After upgrading Squeeze to Wheezy my server will no longer boot. I'm only able to boot, by selecting a previous kernel (2.6.32).

```
linux:~# find /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/ -maxdepth 2
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/modules.order
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/modules.builtin
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/sound
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/net
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/mm
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/lib
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/crypto
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/arch

linux:~# uname -rms
Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 x86_64

linux:~# dpkg -l "linux-image*" | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64                                  2.6.32-48squeeze6                    amd64        Linux 2.6.32 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64                                   3.2.68-1+deb7u6                      amd64        Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                                           3.2+46                               amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

So it appears modules.dep is not being created, even though the install worked. I tried depmod -a, I've tried apt-get install --reinstall on the kernel, nothing is fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running depmod, it only calculates the dependencies and creates modules.dep for the running kernel as default behaviour *unless* you provide an alternate kernel version as an argument.

In your case, since you are booting with version 2.6.32-5-amd64, you need to run:

```
$sudo depmod -a 3.2.0-4-amd64
```

in order for it to create the file /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/modules.dep

From : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/depmod.htm

depmod generates a list of kernel module dependences and associated map files.

depmod [-b basedir] [-e] [-E Module.symvers] [-F System.map]
       [-n] [-v] [-A] [-P prefix] [-w] [version]

Comment: I've tried every variation of depmod and still nothing.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by fixing an issue with depmod being symlinked in uptrack 

    linux:~# ls -l /sbin/depmod*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Nov 16  2010 /sbin/depmod -> depmod.ksplice
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 79 Oct 15  2010 /sbin/depmod.ksplice
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr  7  2013 /sbin/depmod.ksplice-orig -> /bin/kmod

    linux:~# mv -v /sbin/depmod{,-bak}
    `/sbin/depmod' -> `/sbin/depmod-bak'
    linux:~# mv -v /sbin/depmod{.ksplice-orig,}
    `/sbin/depmod.ksplice-orig' -> `/sbin/depmod'

Comment: ksplice my god. How old was that?

Comment: hehe the uptrack package was for deb5 -_-

Comment: Jesus Christ...2011?